# How to delete all navigation item using powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, global-navigation

I need to delete all navigation from SharePoint site and subsites. please suggest any idea to do in powershell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$siteUrl = Get-SPSite "https://sitecollectionurl"

foreach ($spWeb in $siteUrl.AllWebs)
{  
    $nodeColl = $spWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar
    [int]$count=$nodeColl.Count                    
    while($count -ne 0)
    {  
       $nodeColl[$count-1].Delete();  
       $count--;
    }
}
$siteUrl.Dispose()
```

Comment: It shows error when entering Heading(or it contains child) . error is Cannot complete this action.
Please try again.
At C:\Users\Administrator\desktop\gokulbackups\NavExist.ps1:5 char:13
+     foreach($node in ($spWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar))
+             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException

Comment: Ahhh my bad, the foreach conundrum :( , try the edited code.

Comment: Welcome macha :)